# Owin Authentication Redirects To Login again After login (Sometimes)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, owin

Background:
 - I'm using Owin middleware for authentication.
  -Coockies Authentication is used.

Issue:
I have successfully configured Owin to authenticate the application users.The function is works fine when the user login but sometimes and arbitrary the user is not able to login and redirection to login page is took place (Duo to 401 response from index page).

- I've tried to add machine key ,reviewing the session state and all work around but no luck.

Keep in mind,
- i tried to simulate the issue by removing the browser cookies ,the user is able to login sometimes and not able some other times so its confusing.

- Also when any user stuck on this issue its affection all the others so no one can access the system.

Login Page

```
var manager = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
                var signinManager = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();
                var user = manager.FindByName(txtUserName.Text);
  var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(txtUserName.Text, Password.Text, true, shouldLockout: true);

                switch (result)
                {

                    case SignInStatus.Success:
                        //Response.Redirect("/Default.aspx");
                        IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
                        break;
                    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                        Response.Redirect("/Account/Lockout");
                        break;

                    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                        //Response.Redirect(String.Format("/Account/TwoFactorAuthenticationSignIn?ReturnUrl={0}&RememberMe={1}",
                        //                              Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"],
                        //                            RememberMe.Checked),
                        //            true);


                        break;
                    case SignInStatus.Failure:
                    default:
                        FailureText.Text = "error";
                        ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                        break;
```

Owin Configration: \

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            // Configure the sign in cookie
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });
```

Web Config:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="devExpress">
      <section name="themes" type="DevExpress.Web.ThemesConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v14.2, Version=14.2.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="compression" type="DevExpress.Web.CompressionConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v14.2, Version=14.2.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="settings" type="DevExpress.Web.SettingsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v14.2, Version=14.2.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="errors" type="DevExpress.Web.ErrorsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v14.2, Version=14.2.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ScholarshipEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.67.10;Initial Catalog=ScholarshipDB;Integrated Security=False;User Id=sch;Password=Zainer@30051;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="ForeignScholarshipCN" connectionString="Server=192.168.67.10;Database=ScholarshipDB;Integrated Security=False;User Id=sch;Password=Zainer@30051;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <!--<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=Feras-NBPC;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DefaultConnection.mdf;Initial Catalog=DefaultConnection;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="PageInspector:ServerCodeMappingSupport" value="Disabled" />
    <add key="UploadPath" value="C:\UploadFile\" />
  </appSettings>
  <location path="Account">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="assets">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1073741824" targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="3600" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v14.2, Version=14.2.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v14.2, Version=14.2.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Printing.v14.2.Core, Version=14.2.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.RichEdit.v14.2.Core, Version=14.2.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v14.2, Version=14.2.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <membership defaultProvider="SqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ForeignScholarshipCN" applicationName="/" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="SqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" applicationName="/" connectionStringName="ForeignScholarshipCN" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <httpModules>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v14.2, Version=14.2.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v14.2, Version=14.2.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET" path="DX.ashx" validate="false" />
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadProgressHttpHandler, DevExpress.Web.v14.2, Version=14.2.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="ASPxUploadProgressHandlerPage.ashx" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v14.2, Version=14.2.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" />
    </modules>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v14.2, Version=14.2.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET" path="DX.ashx" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadProgressHttpHandler, DevExpress.Web.v14.2, Version=14.2.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="ASPxUploadProgressHandlerPage.ashx" name="ASPxUploadProgressHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <devExpress>
    <themes enableThemesAssembly="true" styleSheetTheme="" theme="" customThemeAssemblies="" />
    <compression enableHtmlCompression="false" enableCallbackCompression="true" enableResourceCompression="true" enableResourceMerging="true" />
    <settings doctypeMode="Xhtml" rightToLeft="false" embedRequiredClientLibraries="false" ieCompatibilityVersion="edge" />
    <errors callbackErrorRedirectUrl="" />
  </devExpress>
</configuration>
```

Fiddler Tracing:
Below is the Request/Response when the user tries to login:
[Request/Response when the user tries to login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOLhz.png)

- Web Server respond with 401 (Access Denied) As below
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dicOF.png)

Finally user redirected again to login Page 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4nFn.png)

Comment: Download Fiddler, and attempt to reproduce the problem with it running, once you do, inspect the request and post the raw HTTP request and raw HTTP response you've received please

Comment: Hi Aydin,please see the extra info from fiddler i have attached.

Comment: Are you encountering an endless loop? I had the same trouble and I beleive I solved it simply by enforcing https

Comment: Yes its endless,the users couldn't login until i either recycle the application pool or fully restart IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Authentication part in web.config from

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

to

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="525600" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

and check if it works

ps: why there are many `authorization` section in your web.gonfig